# Why does my StretchDiBits (windows.h) projected the bitmap on screen so slow and strippy?

Tags: c++, winapi, graphics, bitmap

CreateWindow.h

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

struct returncursorposdemcical
{
    float x, y;
};
struct CustomImage
{
    vector<vector<unsigned>> CImage;
    int long height, width;
};

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
class window
{
public:

    window();
    window(const window&) = delete;
    window& operator = (const window&) = delete;
    ~window();
    
    bool windowpro();
    void stretchbit();
    void backgroundcolor(int R, int G, int B);

private:

};
```

CreateWindow.cpp

```
#include "../Header/CreateWindow.h"
WNDCLASS WindowClass = {};
HWND CreateMyWindow;
HDC mydc;
int BitmapWidth;
int BitmapHeight;
RECT ClientRect;
int ClientWidth;
int ClientHeight;
long int buffer_sizes;
void* buffer_memory;
BITMAPINFO buffer_bitmap;
HINSTANCE myhinstance; 

window::window()
{
    WindowClass.lpszClassName = "Game_Engine";
    WindowClass.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    WindowClass.hInstance = myhinstance;
    WindowClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(0, IDC_CROSS);
    RegisterClass(&WindowClass);
    CreateMyWindow = CreateWindowEx(0, "Game_Engine", "Program",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        0, 0, GetModuleHandle(nullptr), 0);
    mydc = GetDC(CreateMyWindow);
    ShowWindow(CreateMyWindow, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
}

window::~window()
{
    std::cout << "destroy";
    ReleaseDC(CreateMyWindow, mydc);
    UnregisterClass("Game_Engine", myhinstance);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
    {

    }
    case WM_MOUSELEAVE:
    {
   
    }
    case WM_SIZE:
    {
        GetClientRect(CreateMyWindow, &ClientRect);
        ClientWidth = ClientRect.right - ClientRect.left;
        ClientHeight = ClientRect.bottom - ClientRect.top;
        BitmapWidth = ClientWidth;
        BitmapHeight = ClientHeight;
        buffer_sizes = BitmapWidth * BitmapHeight * sizeof(unsigned int);
        if (buffer_memory) {
            VirtualFree(buffer_memory, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        }
        buffer_memory = VirtualAlloc(0, buffer_sizes, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);

        buffer_bitmap.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(buffer_bitmap.bmiHeader);
        buffer_bitmap.bmiHeader.biWidth = BitmapWidth;
        buffer_bitmap.bmiHeader.biHeight = -BitmapHeight;
        buffer_bitmap.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
        buffer_bitmap.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 24;
        buffer_bitmap.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    }
    return 0;
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
     
    }
    return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

bool window::windowpro()
{
    MSG msg = { };
    while (PeekMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT) {
            return false;
        }
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return true;
}
void window::backgroundcolor(int R, int G, int B)
{
    unsigned int* pixel = (unsigned int*)buffer_memory;
    for (int y = 0; y < BitmapHeight; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < BitmapWidth; x++)
        {
            *pixel++ = (R << 16) + (G << 8) + B;
        }
    }
}
void window::stretchbit()
{
   
     StretchDIBits(mydc, 0, 0, BitmapWidth, BitmapHeight, 0, 0, ClientWidth, ClientHeight, buffer_memory,&buffer_bitmap,DIB_RGB_COLORS,SRCCOPY);

  
}
```

Source.cpp

```
#include "../WindowStartup/Header/CreateWindow.h"

int main()
{
    window mywindow;
    bool running = true;

    while (running == true)
    {
        mywindow.backgroundcolor(225, 225, 225);

        mywindow.stretchbit();

        if (!mywindow.windowpro())
        {
            running = false;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to double buffer it, but it didn't work, I tried using bitblit, but it's the same result. Also, when the window resizing, it's not fully painted. And when the window it's not at the full size, it does not look strippy, so my speculation is that either my program is writing the data to bitmap to slow for the refresh rate, or the bitmap it's copying to screen to slow. Sorry for my bad English, English it's not my first language, and I am new to program.

Comment: What does "strippy" mean? Maybe post a screenshot?

Comment: Consider using "break" in your switch-case.

Comment: Im so sorry I don't know how to upload image in stackoverflow comment @Jonathan Potter, but it's like one column of pixel is white another is black and go so on. Also fana thank you for the advice, I don't know if i tagged you guys right, I'm so sorry, I'm still learning stackoverflow.

Comment: You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74884023/edit) your question. The editor has a button at the top that allows you to insert an image and guides you through the process.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed, all you have to do is change biBitcounts to 32, I don't know why that works, might be some to do with ARGB, although I am only using RGB which is 24bits or 3 bytes, if someone could explain this why I need to change biBitcounts to 32, that would be nice. Also thanks for all the people in the comment that are trying to help me.